# Anet A8 inconsistent filament flow

Tags: print-quality, anet-a8, underextrusion

I have been attempting to get my Anet to print for a couple months now. Haven't had a huge amount of time but when I have I've worked on it. A lot of the problems I have had I have been able to trouble shoot, for example for a while I was unable to get any filament to lay, and I have since fixed this issue. Now however my filament will extrude but it is very spacey, and not solid. I have tried re-calibrating the bed, un-clogging the extruder, and increasing the flow rate but nothing works. Is it possible that I have a bad board and that is causing my problem?

[[image: Failed print]

Comment: Hi Rocket_Man, welcome to 3D Printing.SE! Please look into [this answer](/a/2933) and into free spool unwinding and filament entanglement. After this, update your question please by [edit] with what you checked and tried out.

Comment: The skirt _looks_ ok, I assume this is intended to be a 100% layer. It looks maybe that you are set for 3mm filament, but using 1.75? (I had cura default to this on me not long ago).

Comment: Thank you. This turned out to be exactly the problem. It’s printing alright now.

Comment: @Rocket_Man - If that is your issue, please close out the question by posting your own answer! :o)

Answer (score 2):

The skirt *looks* ok, which tends to rule out the most extreme flow or blockage issues. However, skirt/bottom layer can be over-squashed so not ideal for calibration.

I assume this is intended to be a 100% layer rather than infill. It looks like you're achieving about 50% infill, which is a good clue.

I guessed (and confirmed in comments) that you are set for 3mm filament, but using 1.75? (I had cura default to this on me not long ago, despite printing perfectly before, and no intentional changes). One easy check would have been to try one of the provided pre-sliced models that came with the printer.

The effect of configuring for 3mm filament is to reduce flow by a factor of 3 (diameter squared), so even a 50% over extrusion still leaves you with less than half the plastic volume required.

After fixing this, you will need to raise the Z-home position slightly to enable the first layer to extrude properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with my A8 at first. If it *did* work fine and now it does not, then it is not a firmware issue. My issues were resolved when I got a *new* nozzle. If the tip is worn out or squished from crashing into the bed, no amount of cleaning is going to solve it. Also the filament it came with is probably extremely dusty and can easily reclog after cleaning.

Answer (score 0):

It was a stock setting in cura with the filament diameter. Thanks for the help.